# How to run the test case even if assertion fails using chaijs

Tags: mocha.js, chai, assertions

I'm just curious to know how to run the test cases even of the assertion fails within the test script using mocha & chai js.

```
var arr = ["2017-05-04","04-05-2017","05-2017-04"];
function isDate(date) {
var regEx = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
return date.match(regEx) != null;
}
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 assert.strictEqual(isDate(arr[i]), true);
}
```

i want the test case to be executed even if any of the assertion fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an assertion fails inside a test, an exception is thrown, and there's no way to continue execution of the *same test* after the exception has been thrown.

What you can do in your case is make each of your test handle one case from your array. This way, each case is handled as a separate test and the failure of one test has no impact on the other tests. For instance:

```
var chai = require("chai");

var assert = chai.assert;

var arr = ["2017-05-04","04-05-2017","05-2017-04"];
function isDate(date) {
    var regEx = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    return date.match(regEx) != null;
}

describe("date tests", function () {
    function makeTest(testCase) {
        it(testCase, function () {
            assert.strictEqual(isDate(testCase), true);
        });
    }

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        makeTest(arr[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution is working with this scenario, but when i'm implementing it in my logic, it's passing even the wrong one's. Also it is throwing javascript heap memory error when trying to validate 100000 records. In each record there are 100 fields to validate so that means 100000 x 100 validations.

Comment: Also help me with how to pass 2 parameters in the above function?